# What is the pythonic way to pass arguments to functions?

Tags: python

I'm working on a project that almost everywhere arguments are passed by key. There are functions with positional params only, with keyword (default value) params or mix of both. For example the following function:

```
def complete_task(activity_task, message=None, data=None):
    pass
```

This function in the current code would be called like this:

```
complete_task(activity_task=activity_task, message="My massage", data=task_data)
```

For me there is no point to name arguments whose name is obvious by the context of the function execution / by the variable names. I would call it like this:

```
complete_task(activity_task, "My message", task_data)
```

In certain cases where it's not clear what the a call argument is from the context, or inferred from the variable names, I might do:

```
complete_task(activity_task, message="success", task_data=json_dump)
```

So this got me wondering if there is a convention or "pythonic" way to call functions with positional/keyword params, **when there is no need to rearrange method arguments or use default values for some of the keyword params**.

Comment: You're confusing functions with methods.  Everything in your post is a function, not a method.

Comment: @TomKarzes: Meh, Python hardly distinguishes between those things.  A method is "just" a function that happens to be attached to (and accessed through) a class.

Comment: @TomKarzes Sorry, I corrected myself. I was referring to "methods" because most of the cases in the project are actual methods but for the simple example above, I wrote it as a function. Still, everything else in the question I believe applies just the same.

Comment: @Kevin Right, that's basically the definition of a method.  Python makes no more or less of a distinction than any other language.  Methods are nothing more than functions with some additional context.  They may be bound or unbound.  But they are distinguished from bare functions.  That's why there are two different terms.  If you want to retire the term "method" and call everything a function, be my guest.  But while calling a method a function is not incorrect, calling a function a method is.  Methods are special cases of functions, but not the other way around.

Comment: @TomKarzes nobody tries to argue with you regarding the meaning of *method* and a *function*. In the concrete example the *function* should not be called a *method* just because I've omitted the first "self" parameter. Everything else stands. I don't believe it's worth flaming regarding naming of things when it didn't even affect the question and that is what Kevin probably meant.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The usual rules of thumb I follow are:

1. Booleans, particularly boolean literals, should always be passed by keyword unless it is *really* obvious what they mean.  This is important enough that I will often make booleans keyword-only when writing my own functions.  If you have a boolean parameter, your function may want to be split into two smaller functions, particularly if it takes the overall structure of `if boolean_parameter: do_something(); else: do_something_entirely_different()`.
2. If a function takes a lot of optional parameters (more than ~3 including required parameters), then the optionals should usually be passed by keyword.  But if you have a lot of parameters, your function may want to be refactored into multiple smaller functions.
3. If a function takes multiple parameters of the same type, they probably want to be passed as keyword arguments unless order is completely obvious from context (e.g. `src` comes before `dest`).
4. Most of the time, keyword arguments are not wrong.  If you have a case where positional arguments are confusing, you should use keyword arguments without a second thought.  With the possible exception of simple one parameter functions, keyword arguments will not make your code any *harder* to read.

Answer (score 1):

Python has 2 types of arguments<sup>1</sup>.  [`positional`](https://docs.python.org/2/glossary.html#term-argument) and keyword (aka [`default`](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html#default-argument-values)).  The waters get a little muddy because positional arguments can be called by keyword and keyword arguments can be called by position...

```
def foo(a, b=1):
   print(a, b)

foo(1, 2)
foo(a=1, b=2)
```

With that said, I think that the *names* of the types of arguments should indicate how you should (typically) use them.  Most of the time, I see positional arguments called by position and keyword arguments called by keyword.  So, if you're looking for a general rule of thumb, I'd advise that you make the function call mimic the signature.  In the case of our above `foo` function, I'd call it like this:

```
foo(1, b=2)
```

I think that one reason to follow this advice is because (most of the time), people expect keyword arguments to be passed via keyword.  So it isn't uncommon for someone to later add a keyword:

```
def foo(a, aa='1', b=2):
    print(a, aa, b)
```

If you were calling the function using only positional arguments, you'd now be passing a value to a different parameter than you were before.  However, keyword arguments don't care what order you pass them, so you should still be all set.

So far, so good.  But what rules should you use when you're creating a function?  How do you know whether to make an argument a `default` argument or a `positional` argument?  That's a reasonable question -- And it's hard to find a good rule of thumb.  The rules of thumb I use are as follows:

1. Be consistent with the rest of the project -- It's hard to get it right if you're doing something different than the rest of the surrounding code.
2. Make an argument a `default` argument if (and only if) it is possible to supply a reasonable default.  If the function will fail if the user doesn't supply a particular argument (because there is no good default), then it should be positional.

<sup><sup>1</sup>Python3.x also has keyword *only* arguments.  Those don't give you a choice, so I don't know that they add *too* much to the discussion here :-) -- Though I don't know that I've seen their use out in the wild too much.</sup>